# how can I found invertible value in multiple variable function? (Discrete mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inverse-function

I'm trying to find multiple variables' invertible function
I have two question,

```
If f(x, y) = (2x - y, x - 2y), (both real number)
what is invertible function of f(x, y)?
The answer is ( (2x-y)/3, ((x-2y)/3) what I don't know the way for this.

One more, if f(x, y, z) = (y + 2z, 3x - z, x + y)
the invertible function of this is ( (x+2y-z)/5, (-x-2y+6z)/5, (3x+y-3z)/5)
```

please help me for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So consider the function
$$
f(x,y) = (2x-y, x- 2y)
$$
It is a function of two inputs and two outputs. Let's write the outputs as $x_{\text{out}}$ and $y_{\text{out}}$, so we have
$$ \tag{1}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_{\text{out}} &=& 2x&-y \\
y_{\text{out}} &=& x & -2y
\end{array}
\right.
$$
In order to invert the process, we assume that **we know the output values** but not the input values. Because the function is linear, we can easily solve for the input values. Multiplying the second row in Equation $(1)$ by $-2$, we obtain
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcc}
x_{\text{out}} &=& 2x&-y \\
-2y_{\text{out}} &=& -2x & +4y
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and adding these together results in
 $$
x_{\text{out}} - 2y_{\text{out}} = 3y \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad y = \frac{x_{\text{out}}-2y_{\text{out}}}{3}
$$
The input value $x$ can be obtained with a similar approach, by multiplying the first row by $-2$ in Equation $(1)$. The result is 
$$ \tag{1}
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcc}
-2x_{\text{out}} &=& -4x&+2y \\
y_{\text{out}} &=& x & -2y
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now the sum of the first two rows is 
$$
-2x_{\text{out}} + y_{\text{out}} = -3x \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x = \frac{2x_{\text{out}}-y_{\text{out}}}{3}
$$
Is it clear now?

Comment: how about the other question, when function have 3 variables?

Comment: They can be solved with the same method. Are you familiar with solving systems of linear equations?

Comment: Oh never mind...I found the way how to solve it :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel like I helped you, feel free to upvote.